# How do I get Srcsrv with SVNindex.cmd to index extern files?

Tags: svn, debugging, pdb-files, srcsrv

I have recently made use of the SrcSrv feature in the [Debugging Tools For Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), but have noticed that when I index the pdb with **SVNIndex.cmd** it does not pick up any of the files that are from an [external link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got some time again to figure everything out:

To also get the files included with svn:externals property indexed, you just have to add the directories of them to /source= switch!
easier than i thought!
so if you have an external in "Ext1" dir under your Projectdir, just call ssindex.cmd with /source=Projectdir;Ext1 and you get all files in Ext1 also indexed.

I wrote a simple perl script, that handles the creation of the commandline for me, so you dont have to add any new external entry.

HTH, Stefan!

Comment: Come on - you know you want to add the perl script in here :-)

Comment: here it is: http://www.zeintlinger.at/srcindexer.zip
Just hand over the projectdir and it should index every external too. there is not so much error handling in it, so check the output. (i have it under my postbuild actions ("srcindexer.cmd $(ProjectDir)") then you have output in build log. stefan

Comment: Thanks muchly, will add it to my build scripts :-)